# deleting file using sh file in web with php

Tags: php, linux, html, bash

hi i have a php file there is 2 button to execute a sh file and in sh file want to remove txt file i can using sh file from terminal but i cant do it in web browser

php file

```
<?php 
 if($_GET){
  if(isset($_GET['test'])){
        test();
}elseif(isset($_GET['delete'])){
        delete();
 }
}

function test()
{
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/var/www/html/admin');
    $output= shell_exec("./test.sh");
    chdir($old_path);
    echo "<h1>$output</h1>";
}
function delete()
{
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/var/www/html/admin');
    $output= shell_exec("./del.sh");
    chdir($old_path);
    echo "<h1>$output</h1>";
}

?>

    <input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">
   <input type="submit" name= "test" class="btn btn-primary" value="test">
```

And there is sh file to execute or deleting file when i press the button it printed on my screen but didnt running the process

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'delete file';
cd /var/www/html/test
rm text.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your inputs inside a form:

```
<form action="/"  method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" name= "test" class="btn btn-primary" value="test">
</form>
```

Your php file:

```
<?php
if($_GET){
    if(isset($_GET['test'])){
        test();
    }elseif(isset($_GET['delete'])){
        delete();
    }
}

function test()
{
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/var/www/html/admin');
    $output= shell_exec("./test.sh");
    chdir($old_path);
    echo "<h1>$output</h1>";
}
function delete()
{
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/var/www/html/admin');
    $output= shell_exec("./del.sh");
    chdir($old_path);
    echo "<h1>$output</h1>";
}

?>
<form action="/"  method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" name= "test" class="btn btn-primary" value="test">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry sir but i mean thats sh file isnt working when i press the button but if i execute in terminal its working

Comment: @FxBayuYuniantoPabisa Are you sure that your functions are executing at all when you press buttons? I tried it without form and noting happens, but with form I get an error that `.sh` doen't exist, thats mean that function was called properly. Make sure that you that your PHP code are executing at all with button click.